# XSLT : Concatenate a list of numbers with a separator according to a pattern

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't know how to solve my basic problem:

I have a `<Polygon>` element with an `@POINTS` attribute that contains a list of numbers, for example :

```
<Polygon POINTS="337 363 330 221 443 221 472 203 497 225 512 373 494 370 475 392 417 373 385 381 348 421"/>
```

I would like to perform an XSL transformation in the following way:

```
<zone type="Polygon" points="337,363 330,221 443,221 472,203 497,225 512,373 494,370 475,392 417,373 385,381 348,421"/>
```

I want to place a comma according to a pattern, in fact between two numbers exactly.

I tried with `<xsl:for-each>` and the concat() function, it doesn't work.

thank you in advance for your advice and your time

Comment: Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version do you use?

Comment: If I am not mistaken I use the Oxygen XML editor which takes into account versions 1.0 and 2.0 of XSLT and I use SAXON-PE 9.8.0.12 XSLT processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2/3 you can use

```
  <xsl:template match="@POINTS">
      <xsl:attribute name="points">
        <xsl:value-of separator=" ">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(.)" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 2">
              <xsl:sequence select="string-join(current-group(), ',')"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:value-of>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

Or in XSLT 3 which Saxon 9.8 PE supports:

```
  <xsl:template match="@POINTS">
      <xsl:attribute name="points"
        select="let $tokens := tokenize(.)
                return 
                for-each-pair(
                  $tokens[position() mod 2 = 1], 
                  $tokens[position() mod 2 = 0], 
                  function($a, $b) { $a || ',' || $b }
                )"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Okay, I understand better why you were asking for versions. it works perfectly, thanks and nice code.